# iOS - Managing two CoreData models with MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, magicalrecord, core-data-migration

I'm using MagicalRecord to work with a CoreData model, which is likely to be versioned in the future.

Now I need to add to my app a pre-populated database with one entity of about 80000 objects; this data is static and I'm not expected it will ever change.

If I added this entity to the existing model I would need to generate a new seed db every time the model changes, increasing the project complexity.

A better solution would be creating a second model, just for the new entity: the seed db will never change and the first model could take care of its versioning regardless of the new model. No relation between the two models is required.

On top of the existing model I'm using RestKit too and here's how everything is setup:

```
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore =
    [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:
        [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_newPersistentStoreCoordinator]];
self.objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
// bind RK with MagicalRecord
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setRootSavingContext:
    managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:
    managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache alloc] init];
```

The new model will not be used with RestKit.

Is this feasible with MagicalRecord?
I've been through its documentation but could find anything useful.

Many thanks,
DAN

**UPDATE**

Let's have a db model with 4 entities (Foo, Bar, Blarg, Baz) created with the xcode editor.
The model editor has a Default configuration which cannot be removed, so we can only add two new configurations (SeedConfiguration and UserConfiguration), add Foo to the first and the other three to the second.
The two configurations should be saved in seed.sqlite and user.sqlite.
At this point I'd like to run a script which populates seed.sqlite with thousands of Foo objects: once generated this file will be put in the project resources and copied in the app directory at startup; user.sqlite will be instead generated at runtime and used to manage the user info.

When I launch the app in "script" mode to populate seed.sqlite, the two sqlite files are correctly created but both of them contain all the entities, whereas I would expect to find Foo in seed.sqlite and Bar, Blarg, Baz in user.sqlite.

Should I insert the Foo objects and copy the resulting seed.sqlite even if it contains all the other (empty) entities?

Here's how two persistence stores in one single coordinator can be created :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022978/2515181

For the sake of clarification if I could just have one single sqlite file it would be great, but doing so I'd have to generate the seed db every time the model changes.

Comment: This is what model configurations are for.

Comment: How are they supposed to be used? Here's a scenario similar to mine: http://blog.atwam.com/blog/2012/05/11/multiple-persistent-stores-and-seed-data-with-core-data where it is suggested to use two models merged in one single NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.

Comment: One of us is missing something.  The "seed" file should contain only Foo entities.  When you say it contains "empty" entities, what do you mean?  Are there a bunch of entities with default values or what?  If so, maybe your setup is incorrect.  How do you know that there are Bar, Blarg, and Baz entities in the "seed" file?  What do you get it you fetch all "Bar" entities out of the "seed" database?  Are you sure you are not just confusing the fact that the model defines each entity, but there are not actual entities in the database?

Comment: I mean that once the two sqlite files have been generated, opening them with a sqlite client I see all the tables (Foo, Bar, Blarg, Baz) in both of them, even if they are correctly empty. I would expect to find only Foo in seed.sqlite and the Bar, Blarg, Baz tables in user.sqlite, as they belong to different configurations

Comment: Ah, I see your confusion.  All entities are part of the Default configuration, and tables are generated for all entities when you use an SQL store (not just the ones specified in the configuration you used to open the store).  However, the tables should be empty in your specific case.  This is to allow multiple PSC instantiations with different configurations, and is how Core Data works.

Comment: Ok, so as I want to keep seed.sqlite untouched and just version the part stored in user.sqlite for future app updates, would this solution work? In other words I want to use the automatic core data migration functionality for all the future versions of UserConfiguration but leave SeedConfiguration as it is, but I'm afraid it won't work because the model is the same. To give you the whole scenario seed.sqlite should contain thousands of cities (for a store locator) which will never change in the future, whereas user.sqlite is supposed to be the 'normal' app db - versioned!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't want to get into a long answer because I do not use MagicalRecord, and I have NO IDEA how it manages model configurations.

That being said, the way you want to approach this problem is by using model configurations and multiple store files.  The problem is both well understood and well documented.

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/index.html) is a good starting point, and there are [numerous articles and examples on the web](https://www.google.com/#q=multiple+core+data+stores+configurations).

**EDIT**

OK DAN, here is a somewhat contrived (but simple) example for using multiple configurations.  You should be able to copy/paste this into a test file and run it, which should allow you to trace what's going on and get a basic understanding.

Note, that this is not the way I would advise writing production code nor tests (I also don't advise ignoring errors), but I hope this helps explain some things a bit and allows you to experiment.

I broke the code into several helper methods to hopefully better explain.

First, let's create a simple model, with four entities, where we will put two into each configuration.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)makeConfigurationModel {
    NSAttributeDescription *nameAttr = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
    nameAttr.name = @"name";
    nameAttr.attributeType = NSStringAttributeType;

    NSEntityDescription *foo = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    foo.name = @"Foo";
    foo.properties = @[[nameAttr copy]];
    NSEntityDescription *bar = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    bar.name = @"Bar";
    bar.properties = @[[nameAttr copy]];

    NSEntityDescription *blarg = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    blarg.name = @"Blarg";
    blarg.properties = @[[nameAttr copy]];
    NSEntityDescription *baz = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
    baz.name = @"Baz";
    baz.properties = @[[nameAttr copy]];


    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
    model.entities = @[foo, bar, blarg, baz];
    [model setEntities:@[foo, bar] forConfiguration:@"One"];
    [model setEntities:@[blarg, baz] forConfiguration:@"Two"];

    return model;
}
```

Next, a function to assign both stores to a PSC, and create some example entities.  This function also checks to make sure all entities can be accessed.

```
- (void)setupDatabaseWithModel:(NSManagedObjectModel*)model
                        store1:(NSURL*)store1URL
                        store2:(NSURL*)store2URL {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
            initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
        [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                          configuration:@"One"
                                    URL:store1URL
                                options:nil
                                  error:NULL];
        [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                          configuration:@"Two"
                                    URL:store2URL
                                options:nil
                                  error:NULL];
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
            initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;

        // Add some entities...
        NSArray *entityNames = @[@"Foo", @"Bar", @"Blarg", @"Baz"];
        for (NSString *e in entityNames) {
            NSManagedObject *obj =
                [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:e
                                              inManagedObjectContext:moc];
            [obj setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 1", e] forKey:@"name"];
        }
        [moc save:NULL];

        // Should have all of them in this MOC...
        for (NSString *e in entityNames) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest
                fetchRequestWithEntityName:e];
            NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
            XCTAssertEqual(1, result.count);
            NSManagedObject *obj = [result firstObject];
            XCTAssertEqualObjects(([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 1", e]),
                                  [obj valueForKey:@"name"]);
        }
    }
}
```

And a function to check that certain entities are (or are not) in the store.

```
- (void)checkStore:(NSURL*)storeURL
             model:(NSManagedObjectModel*)model
           present:(NSArray*)present
        notPresent:(NSArray*)notPresent {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
            initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
        [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                          configuration:nil
                                    URL:storeURL
                                options:nil
                                  error:NULL];
        NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
            initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        moc.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;

        for (NSString *e in present) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest
                fetchRequestWithEntityName:e];
            NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
            XCTAssertEqual(1, result.count);
            NSManagedObject *obj = [result firstObject];
            XCTAssertEqualObjects(([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 1", e]),
                                  [obj valueForKey:@"name"]);
        }
        for (NSString *e in notPresent) {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest
                fetchRequestWithEntityName:e];
            NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:NULL];
            XCTAssertEqual(0, result.count);
        }
    }
}
```

And a little helper to remove the URL

```
static void removeURL(NSURL ** url) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:*url error:NULL];
}
```

And a test function...

```
- (void)testConfigurations {
    __attribute__((cleanup(removeURL))) NSURL * __autoreleasing dirURL =
        [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                inDomain:NSUserDomainMask
                                       appropriateForURL:nil
                                                  create:YES
                                                    error:NULL]
            URLByAppendingPathComponent:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:dirURL
                             withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                              attributes:nil
                                                   error:NULL];

    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [self makeConfigurationModel];
    NSURL *store1URL = [dirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"store1"];
    NSURL *store2URL = [dirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"store2"];
    [self setupDatabaseWithModel:model store1:store1URL store2:store2URL];
    [self checkStore:store1URL
               model:model
             present:@[@"Foo", @"Bar"]
          notPresent:@[@"Blarg", @"Baz"]];
    [self checkStore:store2URL
               model:model
             present:@[@"Blarg", @"Baz"]
          notPresent:@[@"Foo", @"Bar"]];
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jody, I've managed to create two different configurations and save them in two distinct persistent store coordinators. What I see is that both sqlite files contain all the entities. I would expect each sqlite file to contain only its entities.

Comment: You don't need to different PSCs.  That's the point of a store coordinator.  It manages multiple stores.  The configurations allow you to assign entities to particular stores.  You should be able to do this with a single PSC, and multiple stores.  If you were not relying on MR, I could probably offer more assistance, but I have no clue what it is or is not doing under the covers, so I would merely be guessing.

Comment: My last comment was wrong, I'm actually creating two persistence stores with one single coordinator (see my update in the original question). We can forget about MR right now, it's just a layer above core data and I will take care of that later. Everything seems to work except that as I've said all the entities are present in both the sqlite files even if in the model editor there are two configurations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your code is awesome! See my update, I've added more information about the the missing part which I'm trying accomplish (having a pre-populated seed db).

Comment: I accept this answer as it gave me a good overview about how configurations work, however configurations seem not to be the best solution regarding my requirement to manage a seed db. As stated above with this solution both the persistent stores contain ALL the entities, therefore model versioning would affect both of them, nullifying the possibility to let the seed db not affected by versioning. The only solution I found is using two independent models/core data stacks.